# Connect QComboBox::currentIndexChanged(int) to QSignalMapper::map()

Tags: c++, qt, signals, mapper

I'm trying to figure out how to achieve this in Qt5:

```
connect(qcombobox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int),
        qsignalmappe, SLOT(map()));
```

I tried this:

```
connect(comboBox, static_cast<void(QComboBox::*)(int) (&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged),
        this->signalMapper, &QSignalMapper::map);
```

But the compiler complains about no matching parameters. I know that the QSignalMapper::map() signal has no arguments, but I don't know how it is working with old syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,it worked for me

```
 connect(comboBox,static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(int index)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged),signalMapper,static_cast<void (QSignalMapper::*)()>(&QSignalMapper::map));
```